# How to get sum of every other number in a string using C#

Tags: c#

Using C#, I need to create a function that can get a sum of every other number in the string starting with 64.

```
"64.90.54.28.72.11.38.00.17.45"
```

and it would only add together 64,54,72,38,17 together to get 245.

Can someone please help me write the statement?

Comment: `string.Split` `int.Parse` Linq `Sum` is a good place to start, let us know when you have tried something and you have a problem

Comment: Here is something to get you started: `yourString.Split(".").Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 1).Select(int.Parse).Sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Include the Linq Library at the top.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Function that Sums all the values

```
public int SumNumbers(string s) => s
      .Split(".") // split the string up by '.' to get the parts
      .Where((value, index) => index % 2 == 0) // every 2nd part
      .Select(x => int.Parse(x)) // convert the string to an int
      .Sum(); // sum all the ints
```

Usage:

```
var sum = SumNumbers("64.90.54.28.72.11.38.00.17.45");
```

If this was helpful let me know

Comment: @TheGeneral yea just saw that. will fix it up

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I have edited your question to include a minimal description of what the code is doing.

Comment: @MickyD, no problem, improving the answer is always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
           string num = "64.90.54.28.72.11.38.00.17.45";

            //Since you need number starting with 64
            if (!num.StartsWith("64"))
            {
                return;
            }

            //split numbers string on the basis of dot(.) separator. This will return string array.

            string[] numArray = num.Split(new char[] { '.' });

            int len = numArray.Length;
            int result = 0;


            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                //sum of numbers at even positions only required.
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    result += int.Parse(numArray[i]);//calculate sum
                }
            }
            //print result.
            Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: @MickyD sure, will take care from next time.